# Event id 8306 "Exception occurred when trying to issue security token"

Tags: service, security-token-service

In my SharePoint Foundation server, in event viewer we often find error

> Id : 8306
>
> An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'..

[image: Event Viewr]

I configure IIS settings and Provision security token service as per this [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2493524)

One annoying thing I found with my Security Token service:

When I opened from `IIS > Sharepoint Web service > Security token service > Browse in browser` I get a `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.` error

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$hostSvc = Get-SPServiceHostconfig

$hostSvc.Provision()

$SecToken=Get-SPServiceApplication | where { $_.TypeName -Like “Security Token*”}

$SecToken.provision()
```

You can restart IIS ( IISReset.exe) or use the below PS to restart single IIS Site.

```
Stop-Website “SharePoint Web Services”

Start-Website “SharePoint Web Services”
```

https://sharepointumar.wordpress.com/2017/09/16/500-internal-server-error-event-id-8306-6398-sharepoint-2016/